# How to calculate maximum and minimum in R disregarding the infinite values?

Tags: r, max, min

My data has the format of the example below (on a smaller scale here):

```
a <- c(NaN, Inf, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

I know that if I use in R:

```
min(a, na.rm = TRUE)
```

or

```
max(a, na.rm = TRUE)
```

the `NaN` will be disregarded but not the `Inf`, so that in `min(a, na.rm = TRUE)` the result is `1` (disregarding the `NaN` because of `na.rm = TRUE`), but the result in `max(a, na.rm = TRUE)` is `Inf`.

Is there any way to get, in R, the maximum and minimum of a vector and also disregard the infinite `Inf`, as well as the`NaN` is disregarded?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 10):

```
min(a[is.finite(a)])
# [1] 1
max(a[is.finite(a)])
# [1] 5
```